# Tilde (~) paths do not work in windows neovim

Tags: neovim, neovim-qt

I'm using Neovim v0.2.2 on Windows and I'm finding that editing files using paths with the tilde key (~) doesn't work as I'm expecting, for example if I enter the following command:

```
:e ~\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim
```

Neovim will edit the following file

```
c:\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim
```

Is this a bug or is this not meant to work on Windows? I'm not using any form of terminal emulation, I'm just running nvim-qt.exe directly.

Comment: FWIW, I don't seem to have this program running **NVIM v0.2.3-513-g6762c20af**.

Comment: What, if anything, do you get with `:echo $HOME`?

Comment: @muru I get "c:\"

Comment: Okay, that explains it - a rouge HOME environment variable set to "c:\" - getting rid of that fixed it

Comment: @Justin you can post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Running `:echo $HOME` (suggested by muru) returned `c:\`, which showed that the problem was a rogue `HOME` environment variable. Deleting this variable fixed the problem.